# Make a factor variable out of few data.frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

`A <- data.frame(id = 1:5, col1 = c(0,1,1,0,0), col2 = c(2,0,0,0,0), col3 = c(0,0,0,3,3))`

How do I make a `factor` variable out of it, so it will look like this:

`factor(c(2,1,1,3,3))`

I know how to make a factor out of one column, but not sure how to merge them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowSums`

```
A <- data.frame(id = 1:5, col1 = c(0,1,1,0,0), col2 = c(2,0,0,0,0), col3 = c(0,0,0,3,3))
A$col4 <- as.factor(rowSums(A[,2:4]))
str(A)

> str(A)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
  $ id  : int  1 2 3 4 5
$ col1: num  0 1 1 0 0
$ col2: num  2 0 0 0 0
$ col3: num  0 0 0 3 3
$ col4: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 1 1 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Very straightforward. I should've thought about `rowSums` myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert all zeros to NA's then use `coalesce` from `dplyr` to "merge" the columns into one:

```
library(dplyr)

A$col4 = A %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., . == 0, NA))) %>%
  {coalesce(!!! .)} %>%
  as.factor()
```

**Result:**

```
  id col1 col2 col3 col4
1  1    0    2    0    2
2  2    1    0    0    1
3  3    1    0    0    1
4  4    0    0    3    3
5  5    0    0    3    3

> A$col4
[1] 2 1 1 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3
```

**Note:** `!!!` notation in `coalesce` splices the argument into dots, so it is equivalent to `coalesce(A$col1, A$col2, A$col3)`

Comment: Hi! Looks good, but it gives me an error:
`Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, col4, value = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 15 rows, data has 5`